# Countif in R: Relational Vectors

Tags: r, vector, countif

I'm new using R and I'm having an issue trying to perform a "countif" as in Excel.  What I have is below.  There are two vectors, vector1 being the possible values of vector2.  Vector1 numbers include team_ids to represent the possible teams that may win a game in a tournament. Vector2 is the result of a simulation.

The reason why I can't use a table to summarize the simulation is that many teams won't be represented in game63, but I would still like to return a 0.

In the end, I would like to add a vector possible_teams_prob that counts the number of times each item in possible_teams is in game63.  This way I can combine into a final possible table that has the teams listed along with their probabilities of winning game63.

```
> possible_teams <- seq(1,64)
> possible_teams
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
[13] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
[25] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
[37] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
[49] 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
[61] 61 62 63 64

> game63[1:20]
[1]  4  8  4  4  3 20  2  3  3  1  3 20
[13]  3  8  2  4  3  1 14  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. In general, one can use the fact that R evaluates TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0 to do a lot of COUNTIF-type work. In this case, though, you want it along the vector. Writing a loop would certainly work, but this is R, so we need to use some vectorized version, which leads one to the `apply` family. In this case, the following seems to be what you want:

```
f2 <- function(V1, V2) sum(V1 == V2)
vapply(possible_teams, f2, V2 = game_63, FUN.VALUE = double(1))
```

which returns

```
[1] 2 2 7 4 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This works by setting up a function which create the "countif," between vectors. It won't work on its own, as it expects vectors and the two don't recycle nicely, but `vapply` will iterate the function down the length of the first vector, which is what you wanted.

`sapply` will work as well, and doesn't require a "target value" definition, but can be slower because of that. Your case is small enough it doesn't really matter.

```
> microbenchmark(sapply(possible_teams, f2, V2 = game_63), vapply(possible_teams, f2, V2 = game_63, FUN.VALUE = double(1)), times = 1000L, control=list(order='block'))
Unit: microseconds
                                                            expr    min     lq      mean median      uq      max neval
                        sapply(possible_teams, f2, V2 = game_63) 89.351 92.926 103.31433 95.309 100.371  945.629  1000
 vapply(possible_teams, f2, V2 = game_63, FUN.VALUE = double(1)) 61.057 64.631  73.80298 67.610  71.779 1223.510  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# recreate your data 
allteams  <-  seq(64)
# summarize the game63 data to get counts by team
temp = tapply(game63,game63,length)
# initialize return vector
answer = integer(length(allteams)); names(answer) <- 1:64
# replace true values
answer  <-  temp[match(allteams,names(temp))]
# replace missing values
answer[is.na(answer)]  <-  0
```